# Collapse of Butler-Volmer equation into the Nernst equation at equilibrium potential

Tags: electrochemistry

How does the Butler-Volmer equation collapse into the Nernst equation when applying the equilibrium potential current? I don't know where to start, and this source I used ([https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/butler-volmer-equation#:~:text=It%20agrees%20with%20the%20Nernst,true%20under%20high%2Dresistance%20conditions.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/butler-volmer-equation#:%7E:text=It%20agrees%20with%20the%20Nernst,true%20under%20high%2Dresistance%20conditions.)) uses Bard and Faulkner as given, but I would like to know how to derive it properly. Thanks in advance

Edit: I have to do the first task:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are confused with the concept of *equilibrium potential current*, which seems strange. BV equation collapses to Nernst equation when the current density is zero, i.e., is thermodynamically consistent since it is an extension of transition theory to electrochemical reactions. An analogy would be recovering the law of mass action ($K = \prod_j a_j^{\nu_j}$) when setting the rate $r = 0$ for a chemically reversible reaction in a homogeneous phase.

When this is the case, the potential of the electrode with respect to the bulk solution is named the **equilibrium potential**. The math is immediate from the BV expression and setting $j = 0$

\begin{align}
  j &= j_0\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha F \eta}{RT}\right) -
          \exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha) F \eta}{RT}\right] \right\} \\
  0 &= j_0\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha F \eta}{RT}\right) -
          \exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha) F \eta}{RT}\right] \right\} \\
  0 &= \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha F \eta}{RT}\right) -
          \exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha) F \eta}{RT}\right] \\
  \exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha) F \eta}{RT}\right]
   &= \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha F \eta}{RT}\right) \\
  \exp\left(\frac{F \eta}{RT}\right) &= 1 \\
  \frac{F \eta}{RT} &= 0 \\
  \eta &= 0 \\
  E - E^\text{eq} &= 0 \rightarrow
  \boxed{E = E^\text{eq} = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF} \ln
  \left(\prod_j a_j^{\nu_{j}}\right)} \tag{1}  \\
\end{align}

Although we cannot directly measure the potential of a conducting solid phase, nor the potential of a liquid phase, the meaning of Eq. (1) is as follows. In an electrochemical cell in which no current is circulating between the electrodes, the electrode potential $E = \phi_\text{electrode} - \phi_\text{solution}$ in any of the electrodes, is *only* a function of the activities of the species participating in that electrochemical reaction in the bulk electrolyte solution.

I suggest reading chapter 2 from the book you cited, but if you need more precisions, feel free to comment and I will add more information.

---

**Edit**

Let us study the *academic* electrochemical reaction
$$ \ce{\nu_0O + ne^- <=> \nu_RR} \tag{2} $$

We employ the **current-potential** equation, equivalent to the BV equation, but before making manipulations in order to put in in terms of the overpotential and the exchange current density
\begin{equation}
  j = Fk^\circ\left\{
  a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)\exp\left[-\frac{\alpha nF(E - E^\circ)}{RT}\right] -
  a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)\exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha) nF(E - E^\circ)}{RT}\right]
  \right\} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

When the electrode potential is the equilibrium potential, i.e. $E = E^\text{eq}$ and $j = 0$, from Eq. (3) we obtain
\begin{gather}
  0 = Fk^\circ\left\{
  a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)\exp\left[-\frac{\alpha nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] -
  a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)\exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha)nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] \right\} \\
  0 = \color{blue}{Fk^\circ
  a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)\exp\left[-\frac{\alpha nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right]} - \color{red}{Fk^\circ
  a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)\exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha)nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right]} \\
  0 =
  a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)\exp\left[-\frac{\alpha nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] -
  a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)\exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha)nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] \\
  a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)\exp\left[-\frac{\alpha nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] =
  a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)\exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha)nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right] \\
  \dfrac{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)} =
  \dfrac{\exp\left[\dfrac{(1 - \alpha)nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}
  {RT}\right]}
  {\exp\left[-\dfrac{\alpha nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}{RT}\right]} \\
  \dfrac{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)} =
  \exp\left[\dfrac{nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}{RT}\right] \\
  \ln\left[\dfrac{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)}\right] =
  \frac{nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}{RT} \\
  \frac{nF(E^\text{eq} - E^\circ)}{RT} = 
  \ln\left[\dfrac{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)}\right] \\
  E^\text{eq} = E^\circ\ + \frac{RT}{nF} 
  \ln\left[\dfrac{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)}\right] \rightarrow
  \boxed{E^\text{eq} = E^\circ\ - \frac{RT}{nF} 
  \ln\left[\dfrac{a_R^{\nu_R}(0,t)}{a_O^{\nu_O}(0,t)}\right]} \tag{4}
\end{gather}

- Eq. (3) comes by studying a free energy diagram vs the reaction coordinate. You can relate the changes in free energy with changes in the potential $E$. You may want to see chapter 3 from Bard and Faulkner.
- In said book you will see that instead the standard reduction potential $E^\circ$, Bard writes the *formal potential* $E^{0'}$. This is because, almost in all cases, we don't know the activity coefficients. So the $E^{0'}$ incorporates its dependence (somewhat loosely), so we can write Eq. (3) with concentrations instead of activities. You can write it with activity coefficients as I did, to have a more general form.

Comment: Nice explanation. Is there a way of deriving the Nernst equation from Butler-Volmer directly instead of knowing that E=Nernst equation?  For example, setting E=E(eq) and going from here? That's what my sheet asks me to do

Comment: @Mäßige Hi!I think this is the way of deriving it. I imagine you know that the **definition** of the overpotential is $\eta \equiv E - E^\text{eq}$. So if the overpotential is zero, then the electrode potential reduces to the electrode potential dictated by the Nernst equation. However, maybe I am mistaking your question. If you can upload a photo of the exercise in the comments, I can see what might be going on.

Comment: Wait I think you might be right again. Wait let me upload it as an edit

Comment: Woww that's a very nice derivation thanks a lot :D

Comment: One more question; why is ΔE=E(eq)-E(0) necessarily? Why the standard reduction potential, I thought the Butler-Volmer equation applied to any electrode, i.e. the redox pair not necessarily at standard conditions, just how the potential differs from equilibrium potential of the redox pair (which does not need to be at standard conditions)?

Comment: @Mäßige Hello! You mean why "$E - E^\circ$" appears in both exponentials in Eq. (3)?

Comment: I mean, why is the overpotential defined as $E-E^{0}$? From what I remember, the Butler-Volmer-equation describes, how the real potential at the electrode (when a current flows), is different to when no current flows (open-circuit-potential). An example; a silver electrode in 0.1 M silver nitrate has an OCP of 0.741 V (which is $E_{eq}$). Now assume we want to draw a current of 50 mA, the potential on this 0.1 M $Ag/AgNO_{3}$ will then be somewhat higher (which we call E), and then ΔE=E-$E_{eq}$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Or equivalently, when we apply a bigger potential on this electrode than the OCP, a current flows. But I don't get why we incorporate the standard electrode potential $E^{0}$ in this.

Comment: @Mäßige Hello! Eq. (3) is equivalent to BV equation, as I said in the post. It does not imply a definition of the overpotential as $E - E^\circ$, rather it is an equation some steps *prior to* arriving to BV equation. To convince yourself, I invite you to do the following:

1. Both parts of the new colored equation I added is $j_0$.
2. Divide Eq. (3) by $j_0$. On the LHS just put the symbol $j_0$. On the RHS divide with the blue part or the red part, accordingly to both terms.
3. See that you arrive to BV equation.

If I wasn't clear, comment again.

Comment: Hmm I don't quite get how one would arrive to the BV equation, maybe I just don't see it, where in Bard and Faulker is it?